# How to check the flutter version in a specific project folder?

Tags: flutter, version

I am trying to find the flutter version for the specific folder, but when i do flutter--version i am getting the flutter version installed globally. Can anyone help me out on how to find the specific version.

Answer (score 2):

Check it's `pubspec.lock` file, and look at the bottom of the file.

It will show dart and flutter version that is being used by the project.

Example :

```
sdks:
  dart: ">=2.12.0-0.0 <3.0.0"
  flutter: ">=1.22.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `flutter --version` in android studio terminal.